# Bootstrap control not resetting with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this box to turn from "hitting endpoint" which it does when it's clicked to back to normal. But it does not seem to update its state.

html:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Hitting Endpoint.." class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Hit Endpoint" id="submitButton" style="max-width: 1000px; height: 500px; margin-left: 250px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 200px; height: 75px">Hit Endpoint</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function () {
                var request = $("#requestBox").val();
                if (!request) {
                    alert("Please populate the request box with valid JSON");
                    return;
                }
                $("#submitButton").button('loading');
                $.post('@Url.Action("Run")', { requestJson: request })
                        .success(function (data) {
                            var jsonPretty = JSON.parse(data);


  alert("Was successful");
                        renderjson.set_max_string_length("none");
                        renderjson.set_show_to_level(2);
                        document.getElementById("responseBox").appendChild(renderjson(jsonPretty));
                        $(window).scrollTop($('#pBox').offset().top);
                        $("#submitButton").button('reset');
                })
```

Using reset doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong? Do I actually have to use `setTimeout` like the example here?

http://codepen.io/jmalatia/pen/HkmaA

Cheers

Comment: does `$.success()` work? I haven't seen it used like that before, I either use the `$.post()` callback or pass the function along to `success` in an `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: Yep success is being called.

Comment: I'm assuming you know you're missing a `})`? Otherwise your code works. I commented out `$.success()` and it ran. No need to put it in a `setTimeout()`, they just did that so that you could see it change, otherwise it would change immediately - too fast to see.